# Sum, Pivot, or Case?

Tags: sql

I need the results of my query to be:

```
Company 1 | SUM of amount_invoice
Company 2 | SUM of amount_invoice
...
```

I am getting 86,000 rows- each invoice amount shown separately. It would be really handy for populating the preset charts if my results didn't have to be pivoted in excel first to get the results formatted as I need them.

I've looked at the help fields for pivot tables and I am just not getting it to work.

```sql
SELECT  company,
        CAST(SUM(amount_invoice) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
FROM    invoices
        inner join debtors on debtor_id=debtors.id
WHERE   invoice_date BETWEEN '2019-07-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-07-31 00:00:00.000'
```

Would greatly appreciate anyone who is willing to help me add what's needed to get me formatted correctly.

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output for that sample data

Comment: SQL tag on this website is not meant for SQL Server (MSSQL) i assume you use SQL Server (MSSQL) because you mention `PIVOT` ? The SQL tag is meant for ANSI/ISO standard valid SQL.

Comment: Please mention the RDBMS you are using, like  Oracle or SQL Server, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use group by

```
SELECT  company,
    CAST(SUM(amount_invoice) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
FROM    invoices
    inner join debtors on debtor_id=debtors.id
WHERE   invoice_date BETWEEN '2019-07-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2019-07-31 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: @Lizzie925 keep in mind that if a deterministic ("fixed") order is important your you so your result never changes on different runs.. You should be adding `ORDER BY company` aswell assuming the company name is unique..

Answer (score 0):

Some advice:

- Use table aliases.
- Qualify all table names.
- Do not use `BETWEEN` for date/time comparisons.

I would recommend:

```
SELECT d.company,
       CAST(SUM(i.amount_invoice) AS DECIMAL(18,2))
FROM invoices i INNER JOIN
     debtors d
     ON i.debtor_id = d.id
WHERE i.invoice_date >= '2019-07-01' AND
      i.invoice_date < '2019-08-01';
```

Aaron Bertrand has a very good [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) explaining why you don't want to use between.